# Difficulty getting Saxon into XQuery mode instead of XSLT

Tags: xslt, xquery, saxon

I'm having difficulty getting XQuery to work. I downloaded Saxon-HE 9.2. It seems to only want to work with XSLT.

When I type:

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar
```

I get back usage information for XSLT. When I use the command syntax for XQuery, it doesn't recognize the parameters (like -q), and gives XSLT usage information.

Here are some command line interactions:

```
>java -jar saxon9he.jar
No source file name
Saxon-HE 9.2.0.6J from Saxonica
Usage: see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.html
Options:
  -a                    Use xml-stylesheet PI, not -xsl argument
  -c:filename           Use compiled stylesheet from file
  -config:filename      Use configuration file
  -cr:classname         Use collection URI resolver class
  -dtd:on|off           Validate using DTD
  -expand:on|off        Expand defaults defined in schema/DTD
  -explain[:filename]   Display compiled expression tree
  -ext:on|off           Allow|Disallow external Java functions
  -im:modename          Initial mode
  -ief:class;class;...  List of integrated extension functions
  -it:template          Initial template
  -l:on|off             Line numbering for source document
  -m:classname          Use message receiver class
  -now:dateTime         Set currentDateTime
  -o:filename           Output file or directory
  -opt:0..10            Set optimization level (0=none, 10=max)
  -or:classname         Use OutputURIResolver class
  -outval:recover|fatal Handling of validation errors on result document
  -p:on|off             Recognize URI query parameters
  -r:classname          Use URIResolver class
  -repeat:N             Repeat N times for performance measurement
  -s:filename           Initial source document
  -sa                   Use schema-aware processing
  -strip:all|none|ignorable      Strip whitespace text nodes
  -t                    Display version and timing information
  -T[:classname]        Use TraceListener class
  -TJ                   Trace calls to external Java functions
  -tree:tiny|linked     Select tree model
  -traceout:file|#null  Destination for fn:trace() output
  -u                    Names are URLs not filenames
  -val:strict|lax       Validate using schema
  -versionmsg:on|off    Warn when using XSLT 1.0 stylesheet
  -warnings:silent|recover|fatal  Handling of recoverable errors
  -x:classname          Use specified SAX parser for source file
  -xi:on|off            Expand XInclude on all documents
  -xmlversion:1.0|1.1   Version of XML to be handled
  -xsd:file;file..      Additional schema documents to be loaded
  -xsdversion:1.0|1.1   Version of XML Schema to be used
  -xsiloc:on|off        Take note of xsi:schemaLocation
  -xsl:filename         Stylesheet file
  -y:classname          Use specified SAX parser for stylesheet
  --feature:value       Set configuration feature (see FeatureKeys)
  -?                    Display this message
  param=value           Set stylesheet string parameter
  +param=filename       Set stylesheet document parameter
  ?param=expression     Set stylesheet parameter using XPath
  !option=value         Set serialization option


>java -jar saxon9he.jar -q:"..\w3xQueryTut.xq"
Unknown option -q:..\w3xQueryTut.xq
Saxon-HE 9.2.0.6J from Saxonica
Usage: see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.html
Options:
  -a                    Use xml-stylesheet PI, not -xsl argument
// etc...


>java net.sf.saxon.Query -q:"..\w3xQueryTut.xq"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/saxon/Query
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.saxon.Query
                 // etc...
Could not find the main class: net.sf.saxon.Query.  Program will exit.
```

I'm probably making some stupid mistake. Do you know what it could be?

**UPDATE 1** This command does not work:

```
>java -jar saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query q:"..\w3xQueryTut.xq"
Source file net.sf.saxon.Query does not exist
```

**UPDATE 2** This command works better:

```
>dir

03/28/2010  16:07    <DIR>          .
03/28/2010  16:07    <DIR>          ..
03/27/2010  13:37               849 books.xml
03/27/2010  13:32    <DIR>          doc
03/27/2010  13:32    <DIR>          notices
03/27/2010  13:32         5,473,874 saxon9he.jar
03/27/2010  13:38                37 w3xQueryTut.xq



>java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query q:"w3xQueryTut.xq"


java.io.FileNotFoundException: q:w3xQueryTut.xq (The system cannot find the path
 specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.saxon.Query.compileQuery(Query.java:885)
        at net.sf.saxon.Query.doQuery(Query.java:183)
        at net.sf.saxon.Query.main(Query.java:89)
Fatal error during query: java.io.FileNotFoundException: q:w3xQueryTut.xq (The s
ystem cannot find the path specified)
```

**w3xQueryTut.xq:**

```
doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book/title
```

**books.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Comment: Try with -q:"FullPathAndFileNameHere"

Comment: Using the full path and filename gives the same error.

Comment: You are missing the dash ("-") before "q". Must be -q:, not q:

Comment: In my example, if I delete the "-" in the "-q:" I am getting exactly the same Java exceptions as you. Use: "-q:", not "q:'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I don't have problems with this command-line usage**:

`java -cp C:\xml\Parsers\Saxon\HE-9-2-0-6\saxon9he.jar  net.sf.saxon.Query

-q:"C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 11\samples\xquery\Books\authors.xquery"`

Comment: This works sorta, but now it gives a file not found error. (see OP)

Comment: Check my OP. (sorry, I wrote the comment before I'd actually added it above.)

Answer (score 4):

When you use "`java -jar saxon9he.jar`", you are asking Java to invoke the default entry point in the JAR file, which is `net.sf.saxon.Transform`. To enter at a specific entry point, for example `net.sf.saxon.Query`, you need to use the form "`java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query`".

Answer (score 1):

1. pre-preparations
2. Download the Saxon:
   first you should download the Saxon package at `http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/ and unzip it at some directory like D:\Program Files\SaxonHE9-5-0-1J`.
3. Get Source code:
   If your want the source code, download it at `http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/saxon/Saxon-HE/9.3/saxon-resources9-3.zip` before you unzip it into the SaxonHE9-5-0-1J dir;
4. Build Workstation:
   prepare the workstation for you to exercise: it's at `SaxonHE9-5-0-1J\iexercise` where you can put your *.xq files and its results; you can also make a directory named icache to hold your caches;
5. Let Java know where to find the interpreter:
   To make it work well for Xquery statements, your should add the core package to interpret it to the windows environment: open the command line and change to  SaxonHE9-5-0-1J and run after you copy the `saxon9he.jar` into `jdk1.7.0\lib`:

   set classpath=.;%java_home%\lib\saxon9he.jar
6. Test if it's known:
   So normally you can run the xquery scripts now after Step 4 run right. If you're not sure of it still, chech it with: java net.sf.saxon.Query 
       2.Prepare your first launch
7. Make a file(for example, named test.xq) with affix .xq, .xquery or .xqy in iexercise, its content is displayed below:

   doc(“catalog.xml”)/catalog/product[@dept = “ACC”]
8. Copy the pre-done file catalog.xml  into . /.
9. Run  `java net.sf.saxon.Query -q:test.xq -o:result.xml`
   the first arguement indicates the interpreter to compile xquery file, which is your labor in Step 1.4, -q:filename  is the file that will be compiled with the xquery statements, and the third shows where to put the result; if not specified, is will be dispalyed at the standard output.

The catalog file:

```
<catalog>
    <product dept="WMN">
        <number>557</number>
        <name language="en">Fleece Pullover</name>
        <colorChoices>navy black</colorChoices>
    </product>
    <product dept="ACC">
        <number>563</number>
        <name language="en">Floppy Sun Hat</name>
    </product>
    <product dept="ACC">
        <number>433</number>
        <name language="en">Deluxe Travel Bag</name>
    </product>
    <product dept="MEN">
        <number>784</number>
        <name language="en">Cotton Dress Shirt</name>
        <colorChoices>white green</colorChoices>
    <desc>Our <i>favorite</i> shirt!</desc>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the documentation on saxonica does not say

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -q:myQuery.xql
```

(it isn't an executable jar file and you don't need -q at all if the xql file is the last option)
so the following will work

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query myQuery.xql
```

or

```
java -cp C:\downloads\saxon\saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query myQuery.xql
```